# Why is it possible to change user password to identifier longer than 30 characters

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I found, that using SQL Developer (tried versions 18.1 and 18.3) I'm able to change user password to value longer than 30 characters, which is not possible using `alter user` or `create user`.

I'm wondering how is that possible.

We are struggling to reproduce it, but I can do that repeatedly...

Oracle version:

> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

I'm using "Reset password" functionality from SQL Developer for user that is not connected to DB.

[image: SQL Developer, reset password]

I'm getting no error, user is able to connect with that too long password, for example `a123456789B123456789C123456789D` (31 characters) using SQL Developer, but also sqlplus.

**edit1:**
Trying to use only last/first 30 characters is not working, maybe there is some other transformation, I do not know.

**edit2:**
I created [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3d8dKMpw6I) showing, how I achieved it...

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that, I tried that and trying to connect with first 30 characters or last 30 characters is not working - `ORA-01017: invalid username/password`.

Comment: I just tried this and correctly got the following response: An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

ORA-00988: missing or invalid password(s)
00988. 00000 -  "missing or invalid password(s)"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Vendor code 988

Comment: @thatjeffsmith this is what I meant by "We are struggling to reproduce it" on someone else's PC, but otherwise DB instance is the same, SQL Developer version is the same and I already was able to do that on two different PCs... On the other hand I did that on 3 different environments - DEV, UAT and PROD (on UAT and PROD I did accidentally), I have DBA only for DEV instance. I'm missing something, but I have no idea what...

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I was getting that error, when I tried from sqlplus (modify short password to long one), but I do not think it is correct, for my colleagues it is returning "identifier too long" from SQL Developer...

Comment: the tool will let you send a password > 30 chars, but the db won't accept it

Comment: @thatjeffsmith not sure what you meant, password in my case is successfully changed and I can connect with that long password using SQL Developer and sqlplus, so it is accepted from my point of view...

Comment: I'd really like someone to confirm he/she was able to do the same. I'm thinking I'll record a video of what I'm doing, cause I feel like I'm crazy...

Comment: you can have a password > 30 chars if you have extended identifiers enabled for your db (12c and higher feature)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Well, I believe it is not my case, because when trying to reset password from long to short I'm getting "identifier too long" error (which is basically a problem I'm trying to prevent). Based on [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/long-identifiers-12cr2) it is 12.2, I have 12.1

Comment: suggest you start a thread on our product forums here - with what you're seeing https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/developer-tools/sql_developer